# How to estimate good values for the covariance matrices of imu and wheel odometry?

Tags: navigation, ros-melodic, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is almost no (accessible) information on this topic. (I think) I understand intuitively their purpose. However, quantitatively not so much. Assuming a differential drive robot, with wheel encoders and an IMU with gyros, accelerometers, magnetic compass:

1. How do you find some reasonable
   values for a differential drive
   robot wheel odometry, starting from
   real parameters (encoder resolution
   or similar specs)?
2. How do you find
   some reasonable values for an IMU
   (again starting from physical specs,
   that you can find in the datasheet
   or measure)?
3. How accurate the
   covariance matrices have to be, for
   the purpose of EKF? a)Do you have to
   "tweak" the covariance so the EKF
   favors some source of measurement
   over the other (say when you get
   v_yaw from both wheel odometry and
   gyro)? b)If the covariance values
   are more qualitative, what would be
   some "typical" matrices to start
   with?
4. Finally the values that I use now, without having too much of an appreciation of their validity, are they "plausible"?

For wheel/encoder odometry:

```
odom_msg.pose.covariance[0] = 0.001;
odom_msg.pose.covariance[7] = 0.001;
odom_msg.pose.covariance[14] = 1000000;
odom_msg.pose.covariance[21] = 1000000;
odom_msg.pose.covariance[28] = 1000000;
odom_msg.pose.covariance[35] = 1000;

odom_msg.twist.covariance[0] = 0.001;
odom_msg.twist.covariance[7] = 0.001;
odom_msg.twist.covariance[14] = 0.001;
odom_msg.twist.covariance[21] = 1000000;
odom_msg.twist.covariance[28] = 1000000;
odom_msg.twist.covariance[35] = 1000;
```

For IMU:

```
msg.orientation_covariance = [
    0.02 , 0    , 0,
    0    , 0.02 , 0,
    0    , 0    , 0.02
]

msg.angular_velocity_covariance = [
    0.02, 0   , 0,
    0   , 0.02, 0,
    0   , 0   , 0.02
]

msg.linear_acceleration_covariance = [
    0.04 , 0   , 0,
    0    , 0.04, 0,
    0    , 0   , 0.04
]
```

I'm trying (unsuccessfully) to improve the wheel odometry of my robot, and I'm preparing the details for another question, but the covariances are the biggest black spot for me, so I'm trying to clarify this subject first.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/353897/how-to-estimate-good-values-for-the-covariance-matrices-of-imu-and-wheel-odometry?/) by [vane](https://answers.ros.org/users/54255/vane/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2020-06-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2020-06-29**:
Re-tagged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found this https://answers.ros.org/question/346629/odometry-noise-estimation/. Maybe someone could tag it with "covariance", since it does not appear as a tag or in the title, so the search does not pick it.

---

Originally posted by [vane](https://answers.ros.org/users/54255/vane/) with karma: 35 on 2020-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0